# How to play video without flash player in wordpress website?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

Hi i have website in word press which have a lot of videos.Some videos playing fine but some videos required flash player to play ..I just want to ask that is there any way to play video without flash ..Please check the link below

`http://paulreddickbaseballvip.com/member/?page_id=182032`

Answer (score 0):

I am using WP 4.4.2.. if you simply embed a video file in your TinyMCE editor, WP uses mediaelementJS per default, which applies HTML5 video element to the document and polyfills (e.g. IE) if the current browser doesn't support it.

[image: like here]

So it should work to display the supported video files. Which WP version do you use and which problems do you have?

Comment: I am using WordPress 4.3.3 and the problem is when i click on the image on this pahe (http://paulreddickbaseballvip.com/member/?page_id=182027) then popup opne with a video buut that video requires flash player to play ..I want that video to be play without asking for flash player

Comment: I have no access to your linked page (login needed) so cannot test it. I assume that you do not embed the videos yourself but link to videos which are hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Ok, the screenshots reveal you are using shadowbox to display videos. And your source is an **.swf** file you embedded directly (this isn't a fallback, would have rendered video)? So: If you embed a **.swf** file (=Showckwave Flash), browsers need to have Flash support and if they have not you are getting this message. Of course you can play video without Flash, but you would have to embed Ogg, WebM or MP4 files. Maybe **[this is helpful](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)** to learn about HTML5 video formats/Flash.

Comment: @ ho.s WIll you please let me know how to embed ogg , or mpy videos in place of .swf please please this is the video link https://s3.amazonaws.com/bradwieher/NeedToKnowBaseball2.mp4